# Spring MVC + AngularJS - populate data with json

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I've faced with the problem in integration Spring MVC & AngularJS.
I have following controller in my project. 
When I go to the `http://localhost:8181/{{projectName}}/protected/test` both methods should be executed.
But when I go to the link above only first method is executing. Second method doesn't execute. And I don't know why.
In project http://uaihebert.com/complete-web-application-angular-twitter-bootstrap-spring-mvc-data-and-security/ which I use as a guide the same code works correctly.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/protected/test")
public class TestController {


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcome() {
        return new ModelAndView("testPage");
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<?> listAll(@RequestParam int page,Locale locale) {
        return createListAllResponse(page,locale);
    }
```

My Spring config contains following record:

```
 <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="xml" value="text/xml"/>
                <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
                <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
                <entry key="less" value="text/html"/>
            </map>
 </property>
```

In my "testPage" I have next declaration `<div ng-controller="myController">.`

In "myController" I have following code:

```
    function myController($scope, $http) {
        $scope.pageToGet = 0;

        $scope.state = 'busy';

        $scope.lastAction = '';

        $scope.url = "/{{projectName}}/protected/test/";

        $scope.record = {}

        $scope.getRecordList = function () {
            var url = $scope.url;
            $scope.lastAction = 'list';

            $scope.startDialogAjaxRequest();

            var config = {params: {page: $scope.pageToGet}};

            $http.get(url, config)
                .success(function (data) {
                    $scope.finishAjaxCallOnSuccess(data, null, false);
                })
                .error(function () {
                    $scope.state = 'error';
                });
        }


        $scope.populateTable = function (data) {

                $scope.page = {source: data.records};

        }

         $scope.startDialogAjaxRequest = function () {
            $scope.displayValidationError = false;
            $("#loadingModal").modal('show');
            $scope.previousState = $scope.state;
            $scope.state = 'busy';
        }

        $scope.finishAjaxCallOnSuccess = function (data, modalId, isPagination) {
            $scope.populateTable(data);
            $("#loadingModal").modal('hide');

            if(!isPagination){
                if(modalId){
                    $scope.exit(modalId);
                }
            }

            $scope.lastAction = '';
        }
    $scope.getRecordList();
}
```

UPDATE: I'm totally confused. I've spent several days in troubleshooting, but solution was in adding call of function: `$scope.getRecordList();`

Comment: You're confused about the way Spring MVC work. Spring will never invoke more than one RequestMapping-annotated method per request.

Comment: As I've mentioned above I use this project (http://uaihebert.com/complete-web-application-angular-twitter-bootstrap-spring-mvc-data-and-security/10/) as a guide. And I've found next statement there: "The second method has not URL defined but the Spring has a way of knowing which method it should invoke. Notice that both methods (welcome and listAll) has a GET method with the same URL. What makes both methods different is the attribute produces = “application/json”, this attribute informs to the Spring that if the request waits for a JSon as a response, the second method should be invoked."

Comment: Yes, the second method will be invoked... instead of the first one. A controller method produces a response for a request. You can't have 2 responses for a single request. That makes no sense.

Comment: In this project (http://uaihebert.com/complete-web-application-angular-twitter-bootstrap-spring-mvc-data-and-security/10/) while debugging I see that these two methods are invoking one after another. But In my project only first method is invoking. Or, maybe, there happened some redirection? Maybe, there something wrong with "myController"?

Comment: If both methods are invoked, then two requests are being sent. Nothing is wrong with your controller.